# CakePHP 1.3 : Merge Two Model Pagination in single view?

Tags: pagination, cakephp-1.3

I have two Model with no relationship between them i need to display it in single view file with cakephp Paging or Custom Paging.

Kindly help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, create a view in mysql that is a UNION of the tables in question. Then create a model for that view and paginate that.

Probably the easiest way!

Comment: Thanks for suggestion 

but i have two different database's Model with no relationship between them currently i am using manually pagination with my logic

Comment: @RavatSinh BarryChapman's proposal indeed is the only sane way to do it. What he is talking about is creating a DATABASE VIEW which is a UNION on the two tables. Then you can use this view as a table for the new model and paginate that. I don't think that paginating more than one Model in the same Cake view is possible, especially if you'd want to keep access to all paginated pages via URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use import, http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/936/Importing-Controllers-Models-Components-Behaviors-
and then you can do pagination on both. Note that I think you would have to do some sort of jquery/ajax pagination to have both work properly on a single page.